# Error GTK-warning in Compute-engine Debian

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gedit

I have the follow error, when execute the command "gedit" in debian on gcp compute engine.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn68L.png)

Anyone can help me with this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about the Linux operating system and its utilities are off topic here and should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific problem you are experiencing there is a good answer in [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi) forum.

If you want to setup an instance in GCE to use X, there is a tutorial from the GCE [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine).